# Spring-boot how can i consume XML RPC server using jersey

Tags: spring-boot, jersey-client, spring-jersey

Spring-boot how can i consume XML RPC server using jersey
I am using spring boot 2.2.4
and I have the API from a XML RPC server, can I consume it using jersey

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot provides a start for using Jersey inside your application. If you use Maven, include the following dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

... and your are able to use the Jersey Client or any other Jersey feature